# What's a holonomic D-module from the point of view of de Rham spaces?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, d-modules, derived-algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth algebraic variety over $\mathbb{C}$. We can consider its de Rham space $X_\text{dR}$ as the sheaf on $(\textsf{Sch}/\mathbb{C})_\text{ét}$ defined by $X_\text{dR}(S):= X(S_\text{red})$. There's a natural notion of a quasi-coherent sheaf on such a "space", and we have that
$$\textsf{QCoh}(X_\text{dR})=\{\text{quasi-coherent }\mathcal{D}_X\text{-modules}\}.$$
[See [Lurie's notes on Crystals and D-modules](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/Lurie-NotesOnCrystals.pdf) for more.]

**Can we describe coherent / holonomic / regular holonomic $\mathcal{D}_X$-modules as sheaves on the de Rham space $X_\text{dR}$?**

Here's some motivation for my question: nowadays we can very efficiently establish the functoriality of quasi-coherent D-modules from the point of view of de Rham spaces. (That's the strategy adopted in [Peter Scholze's Six-Functor Formalism](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/scholze/SixFunctors.pdf) notes, for example.) However, for many applications it's important to work with a smaller class of objects. Indeed, the six-functor formalism of quasi-coherent D-modules "feels" dual to what it should be, but the six-functor formalism of holonomic D-modules is perfectly well-behaved.

However, as far as I know, the only way to pass quasi-coherent sheaves over the de Rham space to holonomic D-modules is translating everything to the point of view of D-modules and then working from there. This is very awkward. It would be way more convenient to just work from the point of view of de Rham spaces all the time.

Comment: $X_{dR}$ doesn't really know about the Hodge filtration or the order filtration, so I'd expect any answer to involve Simpson's Hodge stack http://arXiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9604005v1 .

Comment: I don't see something particularly "de Rham-y" but you can characterize coherence and holonomicity on a scheme categorically (the former are the compact objects in D-modules, the latter are characterized on the abelian level by their Verdier dual being a sheaf up to shift by dimension) so you can apply the same words in the de Rham picture. Regularity is a geometric condition though..